# Search multiple tags - OR instead of AND

Tags: kde, tag

Using KDE and just found out about the tags and how to use them.

**Setup**

I have two tags called `first` and `second`.
I have a bunch of pdfs either with no tag or tagged `first`, `second` or `first, second`.

**Problem**

I start a search in dolphin and I want to get all the files that have either one of the two tags. But if I search for

> tag:first tag:second

I only get the files that have both tags. It searches for files containing `first` AND `second` but what I want to have is a search for files tagged either `first` OR `second` OR `first, second`.

Is there a way to provide the search function with a list of tags and it returns a list of all of the files that have any of the given tags.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the answer was way simple. Sorry for bothering everyone.

The magical word was `OR`.

> tag:first OR second

will give you all the files that have either one of the two tags